# Is $\circledcirc\equiv * \omega$? Or is $* \omega \in \circledcirc$?

Tags: reference-request, notation, combinatorial-game-theory

In Winning Ways Volume 2 (pg. 398) :
$\circledcirc$ (sunny) is used "instead of $0\star\rightarrow$" as "the collection $0, \star1, \star2, \star3, \star4,...$" eg.

$$\circledcirc=\{0,\star1,\star2,\star3,...\}$$

This is how I would think $\star \omega$ would be defined.

**Is $\circledcirc\equiv\star\omega$? Or is $\star\omega \in \circledcirc$?** If $\circledcirc\equiv\star\omega$, is there a symbol or notation for the set of all transfinite nimbers?

Comment: Aaron N. Siegel "Combinatorial Game Theory" is a good reference other than ONAG , Surreal Numbers & Winning Ways. One Issue is that not everything is "Standardized" : it is hard to compare easily.

Comment: Thanks @Prem - I haven't seen sunny mentioned in Siegel before, but it's entirely possible I just missed it.

Comment: Does your version of the book have $1\star,2\star$ rather than $\star1,\star2$ ?

Comment: @Prem No ‍♀️ Thanks for catching that! Just got switched in my head.

Comment: You're asking three different questions here, which makes it hard to answer. For instance/especially, if you want references to learn about transfinite nimbers, which have never been talked about in the same "games with entailing moves" context as sunny, that should be a separate question that doesn't mention sunny at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/27904/1/bMATH_2022_TielmanBB.pdf.pdf to get some Idea about the Question :

Page 9 :

[image: 9]

Page 24 :

[image: 24]

I think , it is safe to say that the collection does not contain that element.

Comment: I disagree in the sense that if you extend the theory of games with entailing moves to infinite (nonloopy) games, then I expect a "sunny" that doesn't contain $*\omega$ to defeat the point of sunny, so that the reasonable definition of sunny (in that context which probably no one has written about) *would* include $*\omega$. (As an aside, I'm not sure how you're reaching your conclusion about sunny from this paper that isn't about games with entailing moves at all.) If I misunderstood what you meant by your concluding sentence, just let me know and I'll reverse the downvote.

Comment: No , I think your Downvote is valid , @MarkS. , let it be. I am only guessing , based on what I was reading in that Paper. The Major Issue is that not everything is "Standardized" & "Centralized".

Comment: What I mean by not "Standardized" & "Centralized" : When Details are missing & not given in Winning Ways , then comparing with other articles might not work , because the Definitions have changed.

Comment: While you're right that a lack of standardization is a problem with many things in Winning Ways, I doubt Winning Ways contradicts the paper on nimbers you linked anywhere. This issue here is that the very specific context of the theory of impartial games with entailing moves that stargirl is quoting from in  MathSE questions is a niche topic that basically no other paper/book has bothered to talk about at all.

Comment: A slight correction: Stargirl has pointed out that there is recent work on this niche topic, at least in the 2021 paper [Impartial games with entailing moves](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.11699)